# How to use Webassembly/wasm modules with Vite and Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to import a wasm module into a vite vue 3 project.
https://github.com/rsms/markdown-wasm

```js
<script>
import init, { parse } from "markdown-wasm";

export default {
  async setup() {
    console.log(parse("# hello\n*world*"));
  },
};
</script>
```

it Throws the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@modules/markdown-wasm/dist/markdown.es.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

I am aware that wasm needs to load asynchronously.

On the vite docs it says it needs to be imported in something along the lines of this.

```js
import init from './example.wasm'

init().then(exports => {
  exports.test()
})
```

importing via destructuring

```js
import { parse, ready } from "markdown-wasm";

export default {
  async setup() {
    await ready;
  },
};
```

gives the following errors.

```
md.js:85 GET http://localhost:3000/markdown.wasm 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
md.js:85 wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status code is not ok
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
md.js:85 falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
md.js:85 GET http://localhost:3000/markdown.wasm 404 (Not Found)
r @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
md.js:85 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: Error: wasm abort: both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
r @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
(anonymous) @ md.js:85
wlib.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) Error: wasm abort: Error: wasm abort: both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed
    at X (wlib.js:21)
    at Q (md.js:85)
    at md.js:85
    at X (wlib.js:21)
    at md.js:85
```

What would be the correct way to import a wasm module?

Comment: anything in the [documentation](https://github.com/rsms/markdown-wasm#examples) help?

Comment: note, markdown.es.js exports `{ready, ParseFlags, parse}` and no default export

Comment: I noticed that importing those leaves another error. I will update my question.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this? I would like to import this same package in vite.

Comment: unfortunately I have not. I am glad I am not the only one running into this problem. It drove me insane for days wondering if i am doing something wrong. What I did notice is, unlike the example provided in the vite docs is that the wasm markdown package provides a js wrapper for the wasm module, and it seems you can't use the wasm module without the wrapper, but that does not really change anything. I can import and use other wasm modules just fine, it is just this one that is not cooperating.

Comment: any solution with vite and wasm?

Comment: @aybjax wasm with vite works fine, it is just that specific library, check the vite docs