# What setup to use wasm functions written in go with Vue + Vite

Tags: javascript, go, vuejs3, webassembly, vite

### The Goal

How to use wasm functions written in Go with Vue + Vite ? ( ideally in a pinia’s actions store )

### How not to succeed

On the Go side following the [wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly) with vanilla js it works perfectly and I'm able to play with the syscall/js package ( so I guess my .wasm is not completely crap )

On the Vitesse(Vue + Vite) side following the [Vite doc](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#webassembly)
I’m able to run a wasm function `add.wasm` ( taken from [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/playground/wasm/add.wasm) )

But unfortunately with the .wasm I wrote and compiled myself with go v1.19 I get the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="go" error: module is not an object or function`

If I try to import the `wasm_exec.js` directly in the store and also get :

`Failed to resolve import "go" from wasm_exec.js`
or
`The requested module '/src/store/wasm_exec.js' does not provide an export named 'Go'`

I tried to use the `vite-plugin-wasm` without success.

The issue might be related to the fact that wasm written in go needs to use a wasm_exec.js then a Go() instance in order to make the `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()` work..

Or it’s completely something else that I don't get.

It’ll be more understandable with my [demo](https://github.com/driveralex/go-wasm-vitesse)

I’m out of ideas on how to make it work.. Is the issue in go? vite? Wasm?
Can it be realated to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495141/how-to-use-webassembly-wasm-modules-with-vite-and-vue-3) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72845436/failed-to-use-wasm-function-on-vue)  ?
If anybody has experience using is combinaison ( go wasm vue vite ) can you share your experience/code/docs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

After further research I found my error...

As the error messages suggested, the problem was due to the integration of wasm_exec.js.

I had ended up using tinygo in order to reduce the size of the .wasm generated:
For a simple hello world ~1MB with standard go1.19 vs ~10KB with tinygo… (  btw I will be curious to know the reason behind this massive difference.. because of the garbage collector???  )

But as they mention in the [doc](https://tinygo.org/docs/guides/webassembly/) the tinyo wasm_exec.js is different from the standard go one :

> Execution of the contents require a few JS helper functions which are called from WebAssembly. We have defined these in `tinygo/targets/wasm_exec.js`. It is based on `$GOROOT/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.js` from the standard library, but is slightly different. Ensure you are using the same version of wasm_exec.js as the version of tinygo you are using to compile.

By mistake I mixed the `wasm_exec.js` from go with a .wasm form tinygo… or vice versa idk… and it didn’t worked..

To patch it I use the 2 files from tinygo ( didn't try only with go1.19 )  and I import them into the header of the `index.html`

Vite handle rest and I’m able to call the wasm functions from everywhere, including from the pinia stores.

Comment: did you get rid of `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()` in your `index.html`? I'm getting similar errors but I'm not using tinygo so my wasm_exec.js is correct.